# How to calculate total tickets available and total tickets sold using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to produce the below output using MySQL, which can calculate the total tickets available and the total tickets sold for each event;

```
event_id  event_name     start_date    tickets_available   tickets_sold
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         Test Event 1   2017-04-01    200                 20
2         Test Event 2   2017-04-25    100                 30
```

My tables are as follows;

Table: events

```
event_id  user_id    event_name     start_date    event_active   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         47         Test Event 1   2017-04-01    0                
2         47         Test Event 2   2017-04-25    0
```

Table: ticket_types

```
ticket_type_id  event_id  ticket_type quantity_released quantity_remaining
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1         General     100               90
2               1         VIP         100               90
3               2         General     50                30
4               2         VIP         50                40
```

Here's my SQL query so far;

```
SELECT events.event_id, events.event_name, events.start_date, events.event_active,
(
    SELECT SUM(ticket_types.quantity_released) 
    FROM ticket_types
    WHERE ticket_types.event_id = events.event_id
) AS tickets_available,
(
    SELECT (ticket_types.quantity_released - ticket_types.quantity_remaining)
    FROM ticket_types
    WHERE ticket_types.event_id = events.event_id
) AS tickets_sold
FROM events
INNER JOIN ticket_types
ON events.event_id=ticket_types.event_id
WHERE user_id = 47;
```

However, this is not working as the logic for the columns tickets_available and tickets_sold is incorrect.

Can someone help me out with this query please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  EVENTS.EVENT_ID
    , EVENTS.EVENT_NAME
    , EVENTS.START_DATE
    , SUM(TICKET_TYPES.QUANTITY_RELEASED) AS TICKETS_AVAILABLE
    , SUM(TICKET_TYPES.QUANTITY_RELEASED) - SUM(TICKET_TYPES.QUANTITY_REMAINING) AS TICKETS_SOLD
FROM EVENTS
    INNER JOIN TICKET_TYPES
        ON EVENTS.EVENT_ID = TICKET_TYPES.EVENT_ID
GROUP BY EVENTS.EVENT_ID
    , EVENTS.EVENT_NAME
    , EVENTS.START_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really formatted very well due to my lack of knowledge in SQL formatting but this might be your solution.

```
SELECT  events.event_id,
        events.event_name,
        events.start_date,
        events.event_active,
        SUM(ticket_types.quantity_released) AS available,
        SUM(ticket_types.quantity_released) - SUM(ticket_types.quantity_remaining) AS sold
FROM events
INNER JOIN ticket_types
ON events.event_id = ticket_types.event_id
GROUP BY events.event_id
WHERE user_id = 47;
```